# PHP: move_upload_file() is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to insert an image in one folder, but I guess i am not doing it correctly, can someone correct my code?

```
//Place the image in the folder  
$newname = "$menu_name-01.jpg";    
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"/product_images/$brand/$newname");
```

Where,

```
$menu_name = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['menu_name']));  
$brand = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['brand']));
```

Comment: $menu_name-01.jpg is not a valid variable name. They cannot have "." in it and numerics. So "$nename" is probably NULL or FALSE. var_dump that so see whats going on.

Comment: Nope, still it is not inserting image

Comment: Also I'd suggest you to enable error mode, so you would've seen this during development.

Comment: are you sure your file is uploading correctly? if you are sure the file is uploading, then check for destination directory permissions (if you are using unix OS)

Comment: No, I am using Windows. I think the fault is in the destination path only. I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
$newname = "$menu_name-01.jpg";
```

to

```
$newname = $menu_name.'-01.jpg';
```

Because its looking for the variable as a whole ($menu_name-01.jpg) instead of concatenating $menu_name variable with -01.jpg.

Comment: Its still not working, but your answer is very much beneficial. This was a mistake, but it is still not inserting the image in the specified folder. What is your suggestion?

Comment: @MrTree You're wrong. He used double quotes so PHP replaced $menu_name with the assigned value.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois No, it would take $menu_name-01 as a variable, but there is no $menu_name-01 variable, only $menu_name, the intention was to concatenate $menu_name and -01.jpg, you would either have to have a space in-between $menu_name and -01.jpg or join the string to the variable.